# ubuntu 14.04 can't update corrupted file

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates

Ok I had a security update and it seemed to clash with something I had installed and now I have a corrupted file preventing me from updating. I'm a noob to linux so I don't know how to fix this. I've looked all over and found several people with a similar problem but none of the fixes would work for me.

[This guy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/812896/ubuntu-14-04-clang-3-8-cannot-update-due-to-missing-libllvm3-8v4) seems to have the same problem as me except I'm on a ubuntu 14.04 32-bit. I'm not having the same issue with Clang I don't even know what that is. So I don't know how to change the fix for my needs.

Running the command `sudo apt-get -f install` I get this in the terminal. Someone recommended that command as a fix before but it doesn't work.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libllvm3.5
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libllvm3.8v4
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libllvm3.8v4
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 25 not upgraded.
33 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/10.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 40.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 788253 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libllvm3.8v4_1%3a3.8-2ubuntu3~trusty4_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libllvm3.8v4:i386 (1:3.8-2ubuntu3~trusty4) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libllvm3.8v4_1%3a3.8-2ubuntu3~trusty4_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libLLVM-3.8.so.1', which is also in package libllvm3.8:i386 1:3.8~+rc3-1~exp1~gd~t
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libllvm3.8v4_1%3a3.8-2ubuntu3~trusty4_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

EDIT: Nevermind I managed to figure out a solution myself since no one seemed to know how to answer this problem. I noticed the error code line I posted had the same directory path as the solution in the link I provided. Except it was for my version of ubuntu so I pasted the code and got this.

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libllvm3.8v4_1%3a3.8-2ubuntu3~trusty4_i386.deb
```

Then I ran `sudo apt-get -f install` and now it's finally fixed.